# PHP Trim user input in the text field to avoid user just entering spaces

Tags: php

When user enters just spaces in the text field and submits the form it should trim it and if its empty return an error. I guess when just line of spaces are trimmed it is like empty string right?

At the moment in my php ive got whenever user leaves the textfield blank it prints out an error but i cant get it trimmed if user enters few spaces. It just allows user to submit it.

```
function test_input($field)
{
    $field = trim($field);
    return $field;
}
```

Comment: `trim()` only removes the whitespace from the beginning or end. If you also want to remove **all whitespace characters** from the middle (that is, *everywhere*), use `preg_replace()` instead: `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);`.

Comment: `trim()` should work. How are you using the `test_input` function? Can we see more code? `trim()` will make a string of just spaces into an empty string, which is a falsey value in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coud just remove all double spaces with:

```
str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
```

So the maximum would be one space between two words.